# How to get rid of cygwin's path prefix

Tags: bash, path, cygwin, cygpath

In cygwin, in order to remove `/cygdrive` prefix in the paths, I did a mount like this -

```
mount -c /
```

after restarting cygwin, when I say `pwd` - it gives me something like - `/c/Work/shared/imply-1.1.1` [actually per windows `c:\Work\shared\imply-1.1.1`]
and now I have a perl script that I am running using cygwin and I see an error ... something like - Error: Cannot find module `'C:\c\Work\shared\imply-1.1.1\dist\pivot\bin\pivot'`
that additional `/c/` which is a drive notion returned from cygwin is causing above error (at least one way of looking at it).

Any idea on how to get rid of that ?

Update: To give a better context to the above issue. Here is what is happening -
There is a script file, whose contents are as follows -

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
then
  echo "usage: $0 [conf-dir]" >&2
  exit 1
fi

PWD="$(pwd)"
WHEREAMI="$(dirname "$0")"

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ] || [ "x$1" = "x" ]
then
  CONFDIR="$WHEREAMI"/../conf
else
  CONFDIR="$1"
fi

CONFDIR="$(cd "$CONFDIR" && pwd)/pivot"
WHEREAMI="$(cd "$WHEREAMI" && pwd)"
```

When I echo the contents of the CONFDIR and WHEREAMI, I get the following -

```
C:\cygdrive\c\Work\shared\imply-1.1.1\conf\pivot
C:\cygdrive\c\Work\shared\imply-1.1.1\bin\
```

But the ${pwd} paths were supposed to be resolved as "c:\Work....."

So what I am doing wrong in cygwin?

Comment: The "something like" worries me. Does the error message really include the `C:`? Can you copy and paste it into your question? I'd also expect changing the mount to cause perl to lose its modules -- after all they are now at a different path. What does `perl -E 'say "@INC"'` show?

Comment: In light of your update, ***why is this question tagged [perl]?***

Answer (score 0):

[Don't mount `C:\` as `/` in Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-10/msg00239.html):

> If this is any help for you, I was intent to use something similar to what you want ... I've tried, first on NT4, then on W2k, to setup a *NIX-like single-root filesystem, where `C:\` is the only root, and every other device is a [sub]folder somewhere out there.
>
> Guess, what? It didn't work ... You can't reliably use
>   CD/DVD drives, when they are not represented as disk letters, you can't
>   disconnect removable drives without first breaking the mount point ... it's just too much trouble to maintain.

Also, I have been mixing Cygwin, Strawberry, and custom MSVC builds of `perl` on the same machine for more than a decade now, and I do not understand how the `/cygdrive` prefix presents a problem.

In Cygwin Bash, the following works as expected:

```
$ ls D:/Src
```

In `cmd.exe`,

```
C:\Users> c:\opt\cygwin64\bin\perl -E "opendir $h, 'D:/Src'; say for readdir $h"
```

also works as expected.

See also [the CYGWIN environment variable](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html):

> `(no)dosfilewarning` - If set, Cygwin will warn the first time a user uses an "MS-DOS" style path name rather than a POSIX-style path name. Defaults to off.

Comment: Add an update to the actual post. Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

What about cygpath (Convert Unix and Windows format paths, or output system path information)...

```
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32

$ cygpath -w $(pwd)
C:\Windows\System32
```